# Wpf Datagrid textbox row selected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have an problem with a datagrid where a column is a Textbox with a ContextMenu. But the problem is that then i right click on the textbox the row is not selected. Which means that it can set the values in the wrong place. In the picture below it's shown'en the issue. I have right clicked the top row, but it's still the row below is selected, which means that if i select "Mixed Paint" it will like the picture be inserted below the intended row.  [image]

This is the code for the column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{wpfTx:Translate Action}" IsReadOnly="false" Width="*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Action, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                   <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                                        <ContextMenu>
                                            <MenuItem ItemsSource="{Binding ActionMenu}">
                                                <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                    <controls:Icon IconKeyName="Config" Height="45" Width="45"/>
                                                </MenuItem.Icon>
                                                <MenuItem.Header >
                                                    <Label Content="Standard actions" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                                </MenuItem.Header>
                                                <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <MenuItem Command="{Binding ActionMenuCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                                            <MenuItem.Header>
                                                                <Label Content="{Binding Description}" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                                            </MenuItem.Header>
                                                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                                                <controls:Icon IconKeyName="Edited" Height="45" Width="45"/>
                                                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                                                        </MenuItem>
                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
                                            </MenuItem>
                                        </ContextMenu>
                                    </TextBox.ContextMenu>
                                </TextBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem:

In the xaml code i added this:

```
  <DataGrid MouseRightButtonUp="UIElement_OnMouseRightButtonUp" Name="dataGrid1"></DataGrid>
```

And Code behind:

```
  private void UIElement_OnMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
            while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridCell))
            {
                dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
            }
            if (dep == null) return;

            if (dep is DataGridCell)
            {
                var cell = dep as DataGridCell;
                cell.Focus();

                while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridRow))
                {
                    dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
                }
                var row = dep as DataGridRow;
                dataGrid1.SelectedItem = row.DataContext;   
            }
        }
```